# How to generate PWM from based on an AC signal?

Tags: power, power-electronics, pwm, wireless, simulink

I'm working on a project to improve the efficiency of the resonant wireless charging system. For one of the steps to do this, I need to find the phase shift between current and voltage and of \$I_{\text{RX}}\$. How can I read the \$\theta\$ (angle) and apply it to the controller to generate PWM?

[image]

Comment: One way is to use multiple A2Ds and then do some math to compare the values and arrive at the phase difference.